# How to play the next song in an array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, media-player

For an assignment I am trying to play songs from an array using media player. The first song in the array plays fine, but the next, and last track buttons are where my issue is. Could anyone suggest a way of playing the next/last song from my music array?

None relevant code not included.

```
// Arrays of sound files
private int[] audioFileArrayChill = {R.raw.vanilla_summer, R.raw.lifeline, R.raw.remember_the_mountain_bed};`

// Listen for the end of the track
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            for (int x = 1; x <= audioArray.length; x++) {
                currentIndex++;
                // Play next song in array
                mp.selectTrack(audioArray[x]);
                mp.start();

            }

        }
    });


 // Assigning onClickListener to last track button
    lastTrack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.selectTrack(audioArray[currentIndex - 1]);
            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error", "ERROR");

            }

        }
    });


// Assigning onClickListener to next track button
    nextTrack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.selectTrack(audioArray[currentIndex + 1]);
            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error", "ERROR");

            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the issue exactly? Are you logging an error? What exactly happens when you press the next or last track?

Comment: When I press either of those button the app simply crashes - I feel I am using the media player functions incorrectly (due to lack of experience), I will re run the application and post error logs soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> use below code for next button click

```
  nextTrack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      mp.stop();
      mp.reset();
      mp.setDataSource(audioArray[currentIndex + 1]);
      mp.prepare();              
      mp.start();
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - however there is an error on setDataSource, "can not resolve method". Should I be using a loop?

Comment: whats does to use to play music